# Problem cursor position with JavaScript function: prevents text editing in a code editor, because mouse pointer is automatically moved to other rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm building a small and minimal code editor for HTML/CSS/js in simple Javascript. There is a problem when you write text in it. The problem is that i don't have the freedom to write the text wherever i want, because wherever i write/edit then the mouse pointer is automatically transported to the third line, and not remaining still at the point where i am writing.

[image]

For example, if i point the mouse somewhere in the editor and write a word, the mouse pointer immediately returns to another line (always at the beginning of the third line). So it stops me from writing the word where i want and the word gets written elsewhere. It's as if there were blocks in some points of the lines that prevent you from writing and i won't be able to write where i want.

**ERROR**: Initially, i thought the error is in HTML, then they pointed out that the problem is in `applyColor()` function, maybe it's Set cursor position to end of text code, i don't know. In fact, if i remove the `applyColor()` function, then problems are solved, but as a consequence what happens is that the text is no longer colored. But i need this piece of code (or something similar anyway), because it is part of the function to color the text. I therefore deduce that the problem is the applyColor() function, although i'm not 100% sure. So it should be a JavaScript problem:

```
  // CHANGE COLOR
  function changeColor() {
    var editor = document.getElementById("html");
    applyColoring(editor);
  
    // Set cursor position to the end of text
    var child = editor.children;
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    editor.focus();
  }
```

**DEMONSTRATION OF THE PROBLEM:** I'll show you when the problem occurs. In each of these cases, the mouse pointer is taken elsewhere and i won't be able to write where i want. i believe that by solving the **unique** problem in the `applyColor()` function, then all the problems will automatically be solved, because they all depend on the same unique problem.

- If i try to write a word at the beginning of the third line
  [image]
- If i try to write a word immediately after `</h1>`
  [image]
- If i try to edit `This is a Heading`, it writes a word between `<h1>` and `This`
  [image]
- If i try to write a word immediately after `</p>`
  [image]
- If I previously write any word in the third line (for example aaaaaaa), and then try to write a new word in the first line immediately after `</h1>`.
  [image]

But the mouse pointer can also be moved in other areas (within those 3 staves) which I haven't written about. Of course it all stems from just one problem

**WHAT WOULD I WANT?** I would like that when i write a word (wherever it is written, in any position), the mouse pointer should remain stationary/stopped at the last written word (as any editor or chat works for example), and should not automatically move to the third line (like the photos above). Of course some words must remain colored (as already happens in my code). For example like this, i would like to get this:

[image]

Naturally, if I insert new lines in the HTML code editor, the pointer, instead of moving to the third line, will move to the fourth, fifth and so on. Therefore the problem should be solved by also evaluating the insertion of new future lines

How can i have the freedom to write and modify editor code wherever I want and avoid moving the pointer to other lines? So, how should the `applicolor()` function be fixed?

---

### **UPDATE**: Aware that the problem is almost impossible to solve, i would also like a simpler solution with [CODEMIRROR](https://codemirror.net/), because perhaps it is the most sensible and right one

```js
function applyColoring(element) {
  var keywords = ["DIV", "SPAN", "H1", "P"];
  var keywords2 = ["CLASS", "ID"];

  var newHTML = "";
  // Loop through words
  str = element.innerText;
  (chunks = str
    .split(new RegExp(keywords.map((w) => `(${w})`).join("|"), "i"))
    .filter(Boolean)),
  (markup = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => {
    acc += keywords.includes(chunk.toUpperCase()) ?
      `<span class="statement">${chunk}</span>` :
      `<span class='other'>${chunk}</span>`;
    return acc;
  }, ""));
  element.innerHTML = markup;
}

// CHANGE COLOR
function changeColor() {
  var editor = document.getElementById("html");
  applyColoring(editor);

  // Set cursor position to the end of text
  var child = editor.children;
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  editor.focus();
}

// PREVIEW
const elHTML = document.querySelector("#html");
//const elCSS = document.querySelector("#css");
//const elJS = document.querySelector("#js");
const elPreview = document.querySelector("#preview");

function showPreview() {

  const html = elHTML.textContent;
  //const css = `<style>${elCSS.textContent}</style>`;
  //const js = `<scr` + `ipt>${elJS.textContent}</scr` + `ipt>`;
  const dataURL = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(html);

  changeColor();

  elPreview.src = dataURL;
}

changeColor()
showPreview()
```

```css
#html {
  width: 456px;
  height: 267px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}

.statement {
  color: orange;
}

#editor {}

#preview {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="html" contenteditable="true" oninput="showPreview();" onchange="changeColor();">&lt;h1>This is a Heading&lt;/h1> &lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p>
</div>

<h3>PREVIEW</h3>
<div class="preview-area">
  <iframe id="preview"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest temporarily disabling `showPreview()` and `changeColor()` to start with, in case one of those is interfering. It might help to narrow down the cause...

Comment: @NickGris I tried disabling them. The problem still occurs. I think the problem is something in the html

Comment: I guess it could be getting confused because of the attempt to write tags inside the div - does it work OK if you just put plain text in there? I don't know if it's possible to use \uHHHH to get the < and > in there and if that would work any better...

Comment: @A NickGris Whatever text I put, I encounter the same problem. Even if I write for example qtifgjdfsdjfpdjf

Comment: The problem is caused by the `Set cursor position to end of text` code. You somehow have to rewrite it to focus on the end of the line instead of all text. If you remove the `applyColor` listener the problem does not occur.

Comment: @Kokodoko Well, you helped me pinpoint the problem. Thank you. But I can't remove applyColor(), because I need it to change the color of the text. So I guess something needs to be fix inside applyColor(). Could you help me?

Comment: The code editor is likely grabbing the raw html which includes the elements that add the color. Since it doesn't understand that part, it just assumes they're part of the code and navigates accordingly. You'd need to re-implement `applyColor` as a part of the code editor or find a different editor that natively supports coloring.

Comment: @Ouroborus How can I reimplement applyColor as part of the editor? Could you show me how please? I really can't solve the problem :(

Comment: @Ouroborus What do you mean by "re-implement applyColor as part of the editor"? Write code in html?

Comment: Maybe this article will be helpful. Long story short, when a form element is changed, the browser automatically moves the cursor to the end. So you should save the cursor position before modification, and then restore cursor position after modification. You are adding `span` elements, so you may also need to account for the extra characters you've inserted.. https://giacomocerquone.com/keep-input-cursor-still/

Comment: @MikeWillis In my case, wherever I edit the text, the cursor is subsequently moved to the beginning of the third line. If I save the position of the cursor before the modification and then restore it after the modification, I believe that the cursor will be restored to where it was before the modification. Instead I would like that after editing, the cursor is at the end of the last written character (how writing everywhere works in general). I took a look at your kind link, but it wasn't helpful

Comment: @Nodigap Mike was talking about the modifications that `applyColor` is doing, not the modifications that happen by typing

Comment: @Bergi Ah ok, forgive me both, I misunderstood. Anyway, could you help me? I'm having more difficulty with this question on Stackoverflow than expected. I would really appreciate your help

Comment: @Bergi is correct, I meant that the `applyColoring` function is modifying the content of the input field, which I *think* is causing the cursor position to change. So your fix might be something like: 1) save cursor position, 2) make your modifications, and keep track of whether you're adding characters before the cursor position (and if so, how many characters you added), 3) move the cursor position by whatever offset you came up with in step 2. Honestly I think it's going to get complicated and I wonder if it will lag, but that's the best idea I can come up with off the top of my head :(